# What is IP range and how to identify it?

Tags: ubuntu, ip

In order for some ports to be opened in a remote server, I am required to give a range of IP addresses. How can I obtain this information in Ubuntu? Additional pointers regarding this topic will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the context of what you are asking, I am guessing you are connecting a server which uses high security / restricts their service to a restrictive allow list.

You will most likely need to give them your Internet IP Address. You can find this from your router's configuration page, or easier by going to [WhatIsMyIp.com](http://www.whatismyip.com)

Please note that depending on your connection, it is possible that your IP may change over time.

Comment: It sounds like they're trying to find the IP Range from a DHCP Server Pool which means that it could be either their local DHCP server or that from their ISP. They probably need to provide the range of their public IP address because they are needing to provide it to a vendor who restricts based off of IP addresses. Since they have a dynamic/sticky address it will change and their vendor asked them for the range in which they could potentially pull from their ISP. By doing this it will open up to anyone that has an IP in that range so it's less ideal on home users' ISP than a business one.

Comment: @kobaltz; Yes you are right. I am dealing with exact scenarios.

Comment: Contact your internet service provider. Let them know that the vendor you are working with restricts access to their website by using the public IP addresses of their clients. In order for you to have access to their website, you need the IP Address range that you could possibly get. An alternative is that you can ask your ISP if they allow Static IP Addresses. They will sometimes do this for an additional cost per month. If you go this route, then you'll need to configure your router's public address with the IP, Netmask, Gateway and DNS1/DNS2 provided.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather hard to answer this question with the little information provided. Are you talking about your local DHCP pool or the public IP address from your provider? If you're talking about your local DHCP pool then you can check your router and/or your DHCP server. If you're talking about public addresses then it's based on your ISP and what they have configured. Usually you can contact your ISP and have them provide you an IP Address Range if your computer/servers have dynamic/sticky addresses.